# Display days, hours, minutes in between 2 dates in java

Tags: java, android, datetime, android-calendar

I need to display a countdown timer between a specified date in the future and now in the format Days:Hours:Minutes.
So for example the end date is 4th december 1:30 PM 2013 and right now it is 3rd december 12:30 PM 2013, my textView (or any other view) should show "Time remaning 1 day: 1 hours: 0 minutes"

I **do not** want to use joda-time library as it increases my applications size by about 4.1 MB and I need to use the date/time feature only once in my application.
I am using the calendar API provided by java and I cannot implement this 'timer'/'countdown timer' functionality

Any idea how I should implement this?

**Edit:** my application will only be used in 1 time zone ie. EST, so I do not have to worry about time zone correction

**Edit:** What I have tried so far, get the months of the 2 calendar

```
cal1.get(Calendar.MONTH); //to get the month
cal2.get(Calendar.MONTH);

cal1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);  //to get the day
cal2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

cal1.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);  //to get the hour in 24 hours
cal2.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

cal1.get(Calendar.MINUTE); //to get the minutes
cal2.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

cal1.get(Calendar.SECOND);  //to get seconds
cal2.get(Calendar.SECOND);
```

now I subtract the months, if it is 0 then I know that the difference is less than 1 month, similarly I subtract days, hours, minutes. However that doesnt give me an accurate result. Example - today 6th July 4 AM 2013, end date 7th July 3 AM 2013, according to my algorithm it will say time left is **1 day and -1 hours** and I run a timer to execute this task every second

I need a better algorithm and a better way to display it, I am doing this same task again and again on the UI thread which may cause lag I feel

Comment: Have you tried anything to achieve this? I am sure you must have tried something, if you can post that too, it will help

Comment: Alright, give me a few minutes

Comment: Updated my current thinking/code @Abu

Comment: try the approach mentioned by @SimonSays in the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have two `java.util.Date` objects to compare. First you wanna have some kind of timer that gets executed every N seconds. `Handler.postDelayed()` works just fine for that. Every time it executes, you use `timeMs = futureDate.getTime() - System.currentTimeMillis()`. This gives you the time difference in milli seconds. Then you only need to convert this to the desired format: e.g. `seconds = timeMs / 1000 % 60`.

Comment: This makes sense, so once I get the time difference between the 2 dates in milli seconds I just have to convert them into my desirable format, can you explain a bit more about the conversion part?

Comment: As mentioned above, you just have to calculate it. `seconds = timeMs / 1000 % 60`, `minutes = timeMs / 1000 / 60 % 60` and so on.